# XCode 9.3 console not showing logs

Tags: ios, xcode, console, lldb

Since the moment we added several swift classes to our Xcode project, the console stopped reporting logs. Crash stack traces are missing and so the start up logs when launching the app. Instead, there are showing few random errors with a `[objc]` prefix related to pods. Nothing meaningful.

Before adding the swift classes, the console showed all this kind of logs and crash traces.

I am using Xcode 9.3 on High Sierra.

Is a project based problem or is a Xcode configuration issue?

Comment: If you really think the issue is due to the addition of new classes, then try removing them and see if you get the console messages back.

Comment: I went to a previous version where SWIFT classes were not added yet. Console not showed logs. Then, I guess it is something with XCode 9.3.

Comment: I can see the logs been displayed on the Console app, which means App does log but XCode is not able to display it on the XCode console. As soon as I make progress on this, I will keep this question updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is solved on XCode 9.3.1. Upgrading fixed the issue.